# scrollTop() returning position below element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jquery to highlight my navbar when it passes certain points on my page, but there is one part where the nav isn't being highlighted until it passes below the object. The specific offender is the contact portion of the page.

here is the codepen - http://codepen.io/Davez01d/pen/NxMzYy?editors=0010

here is the relevant html -

```
<hr id="contact-anchor" class="line section-seperator">
```

css -

```
.on-section {
  background-color: #2766af !important;
  color: white;
}
.on-section:focus {
  color: white;
}
```

and javascript -

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var navHeight = $(".navbar").outerHeight();
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
  var aboutPoint = $('#about').offset().top;
  var lineMargin = parseInt($('.section-seperator').css('marginTop'));
  var portfolioPoint = $('#portfolio-anchor').offset().top;
  var contactPoint = $('#contact-anchor').offset().top;

  if (scrollTop < aboutPoint)  {
    $('#home-btn').addClass('on-section');
    $('#about-btn').removeClass('on-section');
  } else if (scrollTop > aboutPoint && scrollTop < (portfolioPoint - navHeight)) {
    $('#home-btn').removeClass('on-section');
    $('#about-btn').addClass('on-section');
    $('#portfolio-btn').removeClass('on-section');
  } else if (scrollTop > (portfolioPoint - navHeight) && scrollTop < contactPoint) {
    $('#about-btn').removeClass('on-section');
    $('#portfolio-btn').addClass('on-section');
    $('#contact-btn').removeClass('on-section');
  } else if (scrollTop > (contactPoint - navHeight)) {
    $('#portfolio-btn').removeClass('on-section');
    $('#contact-btn').addClass('on-section');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To highlight the `about` you do this

```
if (scrollTop > (portfolioPoint - navHeight) && scrollTop < contactPoint)
```

You have to quit the `.navbar` height (just how you are doing in the others)

```
if (scrollTop > (portfolioPoint - navHeight) && scrollTop < (contactPoint - navHeight))
```

Here you have your codepen working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXoLWM?editors=0110

Answer (score 2):

Making this change fixes the issue for me, I think you are forgetting that you are treating `scrollTop` as the scrollTop + navbar height

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + navHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your updated pen is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjveXe?editors=0111). There was a problem in the calculation or better conditions when you switch the buttons:

```
} else if (scrollTop > (portfolioPoint - navHeight) && scrollTop < contactPoint)) {
    // in this condition you stick too long, you forgot the navHeight
} else if (scrollTop > (contactPoint - navHeight)) {
    // therefore you reach this too late
}
```

In the first condition here you need to add the navheight:

```
} else if (scrollTop > (portfolioPoint - navHeight) && 
  scrollTop < (contactPoint - navHeight))) {
    // like this it works
} else if (scrollTop > (contactPoint - navHeight)) {
    // and here we go...
}
```